# paper-input show input and label on top of each other

Tags: javascript, polymer, paper-elements

I have the following HTML

```
<paper-input-container>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input is="iron-input" value="{{name}}">
</paper-input-container>
```

Now, when I start typing in this field, the label moves nicely above the input (as expected). But when initially `name` already has a value the label doesn't do all this and thus both name and label are on top of each other. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `iron-input` you should try `bind-value` instead.

So this would work -

```
<paper-input-container>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{name}}">
</paper-input-container>
```